# Can you use breakpoint in Makefile?

Tags: debugging, makefile, breakpoints

I am trying to debug on very big Makefiles. I asked this same question here:
http://www.edaboard.com/thread324433.html
The thing that I'm not sure about is if there is any way to debug using breakpoints?

If the answer given to me is right, could someone please let me know more exactly how I can use breakpoints in Makefile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use 'breakpoints' and "step through" a Makefile.  There are several recommended methods for debugging:

- insert `$(info)` statements to display values of variables
- insert `$(warning)` statements - it is better than info, because it shows the line number
- replace `$(eval)` temporarily with `$(info)` to see what `$(eval)` expands to
- study the output of `make` parsing the makefiles - use `make -p`
- study the output of the whole `make` run: use `make --debug`
- use 'GNU Make shell hack' (Google it) to log information when rules are executed
- use ElectricCloud make - it has much more extensive debugging facilities than standard Make, but it is expensive (and worth every penny!)

I understand you are a newbie and want to know exactly how to do the above, but I am not going to tell you.  I just outlined the steps above for you and you must go and study yourself.  There is no other way.  A few years ago I also had to study this and while I was doing that, I was asking a lot of silly questions.  There is no other way to learn.

Comment: mentioned "SHELL hack": http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/2007/0703/070201jg01/070201jg01.html

Comment: Overall great answer.  It's nice to have a checklist of things to try all in one place. 
If I might make a suggestion... the last paragraph was a little uncalled for.

Comment: @ChrisMauer Yes I see your point Chris. It was because, the OP wants exact steps; and they already asked this question elsewhere, got a general kind of answer, and was not satisfied and still wanted exact steps. So I patronized a little, maybe I was wrong to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint and step through via **Makefile Debugger**.

https://elinux.org/Debugging_Makefiles

Note that you can install the gmsl via `sudo apt install gmsl`.
But, I can't find out the gmd package. So, you may download the `gmd` manually and extract it in the directory with the `Makefile` you want to debug.